# How to animate the contents of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Go to google, and without typing anything in, hover your mouse over the "I'm Feeling Lucky" button. See what it does?

I can't think how to do that...on:hover....but the actual content and animation itself, how?

Comment: What have you tried or looked into?  Do you want to use CSS3 as much as possible?  Or jQuery for wider browser compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the button that's animating.

They have a hidden div, positioned over the button. It's absolutely positioned.
It contains a lot of spans with all the messages.

On hover, they use a function to move that div around, and make it visible.
It looks like the contents of the button are moving, but they aren't really.

```
<button></button>
<div style="display: none; font-family: Arial,sans-serif; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; z-index: 50; height: 27px; position: absolute; left: 667px; margin: 0px; top: 45px; width: 114px;>
  <div style="left: 0px; position: absolute; right: 0px; white-space: nowrap; top: -29px;">
    <!-- spans go here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

See the value, -29px? That's all that's changing.

Comment: How the heck do you know that.

Comment: I used Firebug. You can see what the the code looks like as it changes.

Comment: Can you link me to a good Firebug tutorial/guide? I tried picking it up and really didn't understand how to use it. All the guides I saw pretty much assumed a pre-existing understanding of how to use it.

Comment: Ha just coming back and seeing some of my old questions from when I was just beginning to learn web dev. Thanks for your help. Was so mystified by firebug at the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class, ie: focus, for the borders and bold face and the toggle it with jQuery:

```
$('#button').hover( function () {
  $(this).addClass('focus');
}, function () {     
  $(this).removeClass('focus');
} );
```

The actual rules you can see Google is using with Chrome are:

```
.gbqfba-hvr:focus,.gbqfbb-hvr:focus{
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #fff,0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
.gbqfb-hvr,.gbqfba-hvr,.gbqfbb-hvr{
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
```

Comment: pdjota, I think they mean the animated text. It's visible on google.com, but not my national version.

Comment: well, then I do know what to suggest, I don't see it either :(

Comment: you might be able to click on a "google.com" link in the bottom right of the page